# How to make a normal user can install package with `pkg_add` on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, installation, sudo, permissions, packages

How to make a normal user can install package with `pkg_add` on FreeBSD?

`pkg_add -r` command fails with normal user with `sudo`. Downloading succeeds, but installation fails with this error message. Equal command executed successfully with `root` login.

```
%sudo pkg_add -r apache22
Password:
Error: Unable to get ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/amd64/packages-8.1-release/Latest/apache22.tbz: Syntax error, command unrecognized
pkg_add: unable to fetch 'ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/amd64/packages-8.1-release/Latest/apache22.tbz' by URL
%
```

Assume my username as `eonil`.

I added

```
eonil ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

code as next of

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

via `visudo`, and added the user to `wheel` group by

```
pw usermod eonil -G wheel
```

. But the user cannot install package with `sudo pkg_add -r apache22`. (not only the apache, any package.)

Comment: Post the line you added to /etc/sudoers for this as well as log output of the failure when this command is run.

Comment: @ErikA I added some more detail codes. Thanks for care.

Comment: What happens when you try to run the `pkg_add` command via `sudo`? Please post any error messages.

Comment: @ErikA I added error message I got. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in env vars.

Uncomment or add line in sudoers(run visudo command):

```
Defaults        env_keep += "PKG_PATH PKG_DBDIR PKG_TMPDIR TMPDIR PACKAGEROOT PACKAGESITE PKGDIR FTP_PASSIVE_MODE"
```